# How to support devices with and without GPS?

Tags: android

My application designed to be used with GPS. But in some cases, there is no need for GPS(in office use) and would be fine on tablet.

Android Market won't let those tablets to download/install app because of manifest. Is there any way I can target both devices?

Comment: I think if you leave the entry off, or specify required as false, you can conditionally target devices. I only recall vaguely from some screencast I watched a bit ago.

Comment: Somewhere in here is your answer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cdvaPyq_eBU

Comment: Nope.. It's not in a video anywhere. He talks about different things. With GPS if you don't put "uses..." it won't even work (you can't get service reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into [submitting multiple APKs](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) to the Marketplace.  Then you can create two separate versions of the application with different requirements, and it will be completely invisible to the end user.